# Javascript (Jquery lib 1.9.1) Mutli file-upload ajax delete files failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, upload

I have started coding this script, which allows you to upload multiple files at once.
So I didn't get to the uploading part yet, but just the file storing etc.

So far, I've done the file adding, and after a file was added, it will create a div so the user can see what files he's about to upload.

Works just fine.

Now I added an id for each div, eg: `<div id="file_filename" class="files">Filename</div>`
Now I want to make it remove if you click on the file name.

So I've added a file remove function, like this:

(I load from document.body cause it's not a natural div)

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".files", function(e) {
    console.log("Sent id: " + e.target.id);
    removeFile(e.target.id);
});

function removeFile(file) {
    var split = file.split("file_");
    console.log("Now going to loop for file: " + file);
    console.log("Splitted version: " + split[1]);
    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (images[i].name != split[1]) {
            continue;
        }
        console.log("removed " + split[1] + " with index: " + i + " and file name: " + images[i].name);
        images.pop(i + 1);
    }

    updateDivs();

    console.log("files left: ");
    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        console.log(images[i].name);
    }
}
```

Basically, it gets the ID of the clicked class, and sends the id to the removeFile function.
The removeFile function will split the text so it will get the name of the file, after `file_`

And then I loop through the images array and check if the name is equal, if yes remove that file & reload divs.

Reload divs function:

```
function updateDivs() {
    var divs;
    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        divs = (divs != null) ? divs + "<div id='file_" + images[i].name + "'class='files'>" + images[i].name + "</div>" : "<div id='file_" + images[i].name + "'class='files'>" + images[i].name + "</div>";
    }
    $("#myImages").html(divs);
}
```

As you see I have a lot of logs updating, so upon remove, I get this log:

```
Sent id: file_images.jpg upload.js:82
Now going to loop for file: file_images.jpg upload.js:63
Splitted version: images.jpg upload.js:64
removed images.jpg with index: 0 and file name: images.jpg upload.js:69
files left:  upload.js:75
images.jpg
```

**Problem:**

If you notice, I've clicked on images.jpg, and then it says it DELETED images.jpg, but then it says files left: images.jpg.

Instead of removing images.jpg it removed the other file i've uploaded.

I have tried everything I know, I know it's the best to solve these problems yourself, but this problem makes no sense to me.

*What did I do wrong there?*

EDIT: By the way, images[0] = images.jpg, I've uploaded it first.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your images array looks like, this might not be 100% correct, but I suspect your issue has to do with the line `images.pop(i + 1);`

`.pop()` doesn't take any arguments and only removes the last item from the array.  If you want to remove an element from an array by index, use `splice()` like this:

`images.splice(i-1, 1);` (which will remove 1 item at the current index of your for-loop)

An example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var images = ["banana", "orange", "apple"];
images.splice(1,1);     // Will remove 1 item at position 1 (orange)
alert(images);          // Should read: "banana, apple"

</script>
```

Hope this helps.